# Failure in build using Travis, AWS Elasticbeanstalk and Docker

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I am facing an issue while building my React project using GitHub as a repository, Travis as CI with AWS ElasticBeanStalk as a service to run my app using Docker. I am able to run my test suite but after that, it is not deploying my app on AWS and also not getting any error in Travis console except below:

[image]

Below is my Travis .yml file configuration:

```
language: generic
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t heet1996/my-profile -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run heet1996/my-profile npm run test -- --coverage

deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: "us-east-1"
  app: "My-profile"
  env: "MyProfile-env"
  bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-413920612934"
  bucket_path: "My-profile"
  on:
    branch: master
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
```

Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things you could try:

Your script command needs to set the environment var CI=true

So

```
script:
  - docker run heet1996/my-profile npm run test -- --coverage
```

Becomes

```
script:
  - docker run -e CI=true heet1996/my-profile npm run test -- --coverage
```

Also AWS needs the access variables to be named differently.

Change

```
access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
secret_access_key: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
```

To

```
access_key_id: "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
secret_access_key: "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
```

Comment: Thanks @R. Erickson it's working but I am getting [Error](https://ibb.co/xSV6KPM) on AWS console.

Comment: @HeetShah That could be anything really. In your elasticbeanstalk web console look down the side for "Logs" and download the last 100 lines. In there search for ERROR or something similar. That should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the option --coverage, your test will hang, waiting for input. Hence the message: "...no output has been received in the last 10m0s...".

At a certain point, --coverage was probably able to stop tests (as some used for that purpose), but I guess it was not meant for that and subsequent versions of docker removed that behavior.

Your test must conclude and the conclusion be a success for the deployment by Travis to begin.

Use instead the option --watchAll=false. So you should have:

```
...
script:
  - docker run heet1996/my-profile npm run test -- --watchAll=false
...
```

That would take care of the obvious issue of your test never concluding (that could be the only issue). Afterward, make sure that your tests are successful. Then, you can worry about other issues such as authentication on AWS, etc...